# Is it possible to vertically align various fluid relative or static positioned elements inside fluid div?

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment, fluid-layout

I've got such code:

```
<div id="virtual-studio" class="banner-box">

    <a href="some_url" target="_blank">
        <img src="some.png" alt="some_alt" class="logo">
    </a>

    <div class="banner-text">
        <img src="some.png" alt="" />
    </div>

    <a href="some_url" target="_blank" class="see-more-button">
        <img src="some.png" alt="some_alt" />
    </a>

</div>
```

and here are styles to this banner-box:

```
.banner-box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 26%;
    max-width: 26%;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.banner-box a {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.logo {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
}    

.banner-text {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.banner-text img {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.see-more-button {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.see-more-button img {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

There are three such boxes, horizontally aligned - left, middle, right - and they're inside bigger box named **#content**, which is in another box named **#container**.

My whole layout is meant to be 100% fluid - I haven't used pixels anywhere - just percentages.

I'd like to structurize this three images, that they will be aligned vertically inside box, on top-middle-bottom style, but without need to making even one element fixed size.

Every element in layout should have percentage-based size.
Also images I use, should be fluid.

Here's whole .html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
        <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,300,400italic,400,600italic,600,700italic,700,800italic,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="wrapper">

            <div id="header">

                <div>
                    <img src="some.png" alt="some-alt" />
                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="container">

                <div id="content">

                    <div id="virtual-studio" class="banner-box">

                        <a href="some-url.com" target="_blank">
                            <img src="some.png" alt="some-alt" class="logo">
                        </a>

                        <div class="banner-text">
                            <img src="some.png" alt="some-alt" />
                        </div>

                        <a href="some-url.com" target="_blank" class="see-more-button">
                            <img src="some.png" alt="some-alt" />
                        </a>

                    </div>

                    <div id="mu-interactive" class="banner-box">

                        <a href="some-url.com" target="_blank">
                            <img src="some.png" alt="some-alt" class="logo">
                        </a>

                        <div class="banner-text">
                            <img src="some.png" alt="some-alt" />
                        </div>

                        <a href="some-url.com" target="_blank" class="see-more-button">
                            <img src="some.png" alt="some-alt" />
                        </a>

                    </div>

                    <div id="mu-animation" class="banner-box">

                        <a href="some-url.com" target="_blank">
                            <img src="some.png" alt="some-alt" class="logo">
                        </a>

                        <div class="banner-text">
                            <img src="some.png" alt="some-alt" />
                        </div>

                        <a href="some-url.com" target="_blank" class="see-more-button">
                            <img src="see-more.png" alt="some-alt" />
                        </a>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div id="shadows">
                    <img src="shadows.png" alt="Shadows" />
                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="footer">

                    <img src="footer-line.png" alt="Footer.png" />
                    <div id="contact">
                        <p><span>company</span> co.</p>
                        <p>mail: <span>contact&#64;mail&#46;com</span></p>
                    </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

and .css:

```
/*@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,300,400italic,400,600italic,600,700italic,700,800italic,800");
*/

/** { 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    /*-moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    /*box-sizing: border-box; /* Opera/IE 8+ */
/*}*/

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /*-webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: 100% 100%;*/
}

body {
    /*position: relative;*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    /*font-size: 15px;*/
    font: 1em 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    /*font: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;*/
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    /*display: block;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;*/
}

#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 10% 15%;
}

#header {
    /*position: relative;*/
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 24%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 auto;
}

#header div {
    /*position: relative;*/
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 auto;
}

#header img {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    /*width: auto;
    height: auto;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;*/
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 7% 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#content {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.banner-box {
    /*position: relative;*/
    display: inline-block;
    width: 26%;
    max-width: 26%;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.banner-box a {
    /*position: relative;*/
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    /*min-height: 50%;
    height: 50%;*/
    top: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.logo {
    position: relative;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    /*width: 100%;
    height: 100%;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*vertical-align: top;*/
}

.logo:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    transform:scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.1); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.1); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.1); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:scale(1.1); /* Opera */
}    

.banner-text {
    /*position: relative;*/
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    /*height: 25%;
    min-height: 25%;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 50%;
    /*padding:  5% 0;
    /*font: 0/0 a;
    vertical-align: middle;*/
}

.banner-text img {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*vertical-align: middle;*/
}

.see-more-button {
    /*position: relative;*/
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    /*height: 25%;
    min-height: 25%;*/
    /*vertical-align: bottom;*/
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.see-more-button img {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    /*width: 100%;
    /*height: 100%;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*font: 0/0 a;*/
}

#virtual-studio {
    /*position: relative;
    display: inline-block;*/
    float: left;
    /*width: 290px;
    margin: 0 auto;*//*margin: auto;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;*/
}

/*#virtual-studio a {

}

#virtual-studio a img {

}*/


/*#mu-interactive {
    /*position: relative;
    display: inline-block;*/
    /*float: left;*/
    /*width: 290px;
    margin: 0 auto;*//*margin: auto;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}*/

/*#mu-interactive a {

}

#mu-interactive a img {

}*/

#mu-animation {
    /*position: relative;
    display: inline-block;*/
    float: right;
    /*width: 290px;
    margin: 0 auto;*//*margin: auto;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;*/
}
/*
#mu-animation a {

}

#mu-animation a img {

}/*

/*#virtual-studio a img:hover, #mu-interactive a img:hover, #mu-animation a img:hover {
    width: 101%;
    height: 101%;
}*/

#shadows {
    /*position: relative;*/
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#shadows img {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    /*height: 100%;*/
    /*bottom: 15%;*/
    /*height: 100%;
    top: 0; right: 0; left: 0;*/
}

#footer {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    /*font-size: 1em;*/
    /*top: 0; right: 0; left: 0;*/
}

#footer img {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    width: 95%;
    /*height: auto;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*padding: 2% 0 0 0;
    /*top: 0; right: 0; left: 0;*/
}

#footer #contact {
    position: relative;
    margin: 1% 0 0 0;
}

#footer p {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    /*position: relative;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #AFBEA5;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
}

#footer span {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #BDC9AF;
}

@media only screen
and (max-device-width: 320px) {
    html {
    background: url('some-background-320.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
}

@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 321px)
and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    html {
    background: url('some-background-480.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
}

@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 481px)
and (max-device-width: 768px) {
    html {
    background: url('some-background-768.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
}

@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 767px)
and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    html {
    background: url('some-background-1024.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
}

@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 1025px)
and (max-device-width: 1680px) {
    html {
    background: url('some-background-1680.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
}

@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 1681px) {
    html {
    background: url('some-background-1920.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
}
```

I've tried using **position: absolute;** or changing to **display: table-cell;** but nothing worked - maybe I've made mistakes somewhere, when trying this..

When positioning images to absolute, they've collapsed out from own containers and even from **#banner-box** container

My main problem is I don't know how to make every element of page behave like fixed-size but still be described through percents.
And, how to structurize this #banner-box container, to make it stretch into **#content** 100% height, and then align those thre images vertically inside **#banner-box**.

I'd strongly prefer not to use a line of JS, no frameworks and base my layout 100% on percentages, so that's why I' racking my brains on this problem. I'd like to use only XHTML/CSS2 or HTML5/CSS3 but to make this website work on IE8+ and modern browsers.

But if there won't be any chance not using even a pixel, what grid size (website fixed size, not grid framework like Bootstrap .etc) would be best for me? 960px or 1024px?

Cheers and sorry if my simple&stupid (probably), yet tough for me, problem is annoying for ya.

Comment: tl:dr, have a demo for us to use?

Comment: Usually you will have a better chance to get the answers you're looking for, and get them faster, by making your code short and to the point. Try removing any code that isn't directly involved in the part where your problem occurs, or try making a simplified analogous code that exhibits the same problem for you.

Comment: Absolute containers are *outside the flow of normal content*, similar to floats, so it's no surprise they collapse. You may prefer to not use any JS, but you will pretty much have to to center vertically. There is no fool-proof way in CSS, unless you confine it to pre-determined constraints. Also, **copy your relevant code to a jsfiddle so that people can tweak your code!!!***

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read this tutorial: http://tinyurl.com/qb6q78o

Specifically the Tuscany Luxury Resorts example, which you can check live in here: http://cameronmoll.com/projects/book/

It is a totally fluid design, including images. I programmed my own version in a couple of days having only 10 days of experience in CSS.